# Add Javascript In Webview In Android

Tags: javascript, android

I want to add leadbolt banner ad in a webview. Here is the ad code below

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ad.leadboltads.net/show_app_ad.js?section_id=xxxxxxxxx"></script>
```

How will I add this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WebView have a method called loadData(). Allow webview load html code directly.You could have a try.

```
String js_str = "<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ad.leadboltads.net/show_app_ad.js?section_id=xxxxxxxxx'></script>"

WebView webview = new WebView();

webview.loadData(js_str, null, null);
```

Comment: You may want to escape the quotes within your string.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
WebView wv = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webViewad); 
wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
StringBuilder htmlData = new StringBuilder("<html>"); 
htmlData.append("<head><title>Ad</title></head>"); 
htmlData.append("<body>"); 
htmlData.append("<script type=\"text/javascript\" 
src=\"http://ad.leadboltads.net/show_app_ad.js?section_id=YOUR_ID\"></script>"); 
htmlData.append("</body>"); 
htmlData.append("</html>"); 
wv.loadData(htmlData.toString(),"text/html", "ISO 8859-1");
```